# Why is this only returning "yes"

Tags: c++, console-application

```
int OnLoad() {
cout << "Hi whats your name? ";
cin >> name;
system("cls");
cout << "Hi " << name << "." << " Are you here to Take Over the city from zombies?"<< endl;
cin >> userInput;
if (userInput == "yes" || "Yes") {
    cout << "Yes" << endl;
}
else if (userInput == "no" || "No") {
    cout << "No" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "I don't understand." << endl;
}
return 0;
}

int main() {
OnLoad();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

This code only returns Yes back, after the console window pops up and ask are you here to take over the city from zombies even after i type no it returns yes!

Comment: `|| "Yes"` does not do what you think. It actually evaluates to true always! You want `if ( (userInput == "yes") || (userInput == "Yes"))`

Comment: I am sure there are hundreds (if not thousands) of duplicates of this question so I will not post a formal answer.

Comment: Thank you, I actually started to try this but i thought it was wrong. Lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (userInput == "yes" || "Yes")
```

actually means

```
if ((userInput == "yes") || ("Yes"))
```

It's logical OR between two expressions: `userInput == "yes"` and `"Yes"`. The first one is correct and evaluates to `bool` directly. The second one is just a `char*` that will be converted to `bool` implicitly. Since it's a compile time string it cannot be `nullptr`, which means it will always evaluate to `true`. And that, in turn, means the whole condition is always `true` (that's how logical OR works). 
The correct code is

```
if (userInput == "yes" || userInput == "Yes")
```

P. S. This is why I always recommend compiling with the highest warning level possible (`/W4` for MSVC, `-Wall -pedantic-errors` for GCC and clang). Most compilers will generate a warning in this case.

Answer (score 0):

that's not how the || operator works, if you just put "Yes" as a condition it will always evaluate to true

```
if (userInput == "yes" || userInput == "Yes") {
    cout << "Yes" << endl;
}
```

the reason why is because of precedence

```
userInput == "yes"
```

and

```
userInput == "Yes"
```

get evaluated before || ( logical OR)